# Regexp not parsed

Tags: javascript, regex

I solve a problem of tag substitution in a string, for example:
"Hello, #name !" should evaluate to smth like: "Hello, John !"
I tested regexp based algorithm and it works fine. The problem is that when I try to add tag to search dynamically it somehow not parsed.
All code:

```
    var replaceTags = function(str, tags) {
        var tagPattern = { search: "(^|[^#])((##)*)#", copy: "$1$2" };
        var result;
        var tagNames = Object.keys(tags);
        for(var i = 0; i < tagNames.length; i++) {
            var subDollarEscaped = tags[tagNames[i]].replace(RegExp("\\$", "g"), "$$$$");
            result = str.replace(RegExp(tagPattern.search + tagNames[i], "g"), tagPattern.copy + subDollarEscaped);
        }
        result = result.replace(RegExp("##", "g"), "#");

        return result;
    };
```

The problem is in this line:

```
result = str.replace(RegExp(tagPattern.search + tagNames[i], "g"), tagPattern.copy + subDollarEscaped);
```

Somehow strings are not concatenated correctly. For example, changing line to this works:

```
result = str.replace(RegExp(tagPattern.search + "name", "g"), tagPattern.copy + subDollarEscaped);
```

According to doc Object.keys() should return string array, but it looks like it doesn't. I made console output to be sure that for tag "name"

```
tagPattern.search + tagNames[i]
```

really evaluates to

```
(^|[^#])((##)*)#name
```

So I'm really confused.

Comment: Different converstions of tagNames[i] to string also don't work.

Comment: Your function never uses `str`, and `result` never gets set to a value other than the replace on itself. Should the third line read `var result=str;` or something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, in my real version it uses str of cause, I've changed the example

Comment: But now result only is assigned the value of the last replace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet that's based on your code, and it seems to work.

```js
var str = 'Hello there #name, occupant of room #room!',
    tags = {
        name:'Fomin',
        room:'123'
    },
    tagPattern = { search: "(^|[^#])((##)*)#", copy: "$1$2" },
    result=str,
    tagNames = Object.keys(tags),
    subDollarEscaped ;

for(var i = 0; i < tagNames.length; i++) {
  subDollarEscaped = tags[tagNames[i]].replace(RegExp("\\$", "g"), "$$$$");
  result = result.replace(RegExp(tagPattern.search + tagNames[i], "g"), tagPattern.copy + subDollarEscaped);
}

result = result.replace(RegExp("##", "g"), "#");
console.log('result:'+result);
```

Difference is I assign `str` to `result` to begin with, and then assigns `result` with the result of the replace.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. I really assigned result to str evaluation on every cycle tick. Sorry.

Comment: Have you read the comment after the code? **"Difference is I assign str to result to begin with, and then assigns result with the result of the replace."**